# How to run a batch exclusion list in Google Big Query whit Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have a list of 14,000 delete commands to be executed in Big Query, to execute them one by one in a for loop ends up being quite slow, is there a way to execute all these deletes in batch at once instead of one to one? It is worth mentioning that even if I send a lot of deletes at a time, BigQuery executes them one by one.

Example of delete commands:

```
delete from `center_shoppings.stores.orders` as o 
                        where o.store_reference = '554151-16161-23230'
                        and o.store_id = 23613213
                        and o.day_sold = '2023-03-10';
delete from `center_shoppings.stores.orders` as o 
                        where o.store_reference = '156616-12303-2646213'
                        and o.store_id = 61623265
                        and o.day_sold = '2023-03-11';
delete from `center_shoppings.stores.orders` as o 
                        where o.store_reference = '6515156-26151651651-2616'
                        and o.store_id = 1652612
                        and o.day_sold = '2023-03-12';
delete from `center_shoppings.stores.orders` as o 
                        where o.store_reference = '54165-45115555-11'
                        and o.store_id = 545615133
                        and o.day_sold = '2023-03-10';
delete from `center_shoppings.stores.orders` as o 
                        where o.store_reference = '5415151-61662626-55555555'
                        and o.store_id = 6562626
                        and o.day_sold = '2023-03-11';
delete from `center_shoppings.stores.orders` as o 
                        where o.store_reference = '51515-22222'
                        and o.store_id = 51651515
                        and o.day_sold = '2023-03-12';
```

Example of my actual code running the delete list:

```
    for delete in all_deletes:
        job = client.query(delete)
        job.result()
```

I need a faster way to perform all these deletes, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps referring to batch [query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#batch)(sample code included)?

> "With batch query jobs, BigQuery queues your queries and starts them when idle resources are available in the BigQuery shared resource pool."

Also a reminder that you can run a maximum of 10 concurrent batch queries in your project. For quota and resources limit please [visit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#concurrent_rate_batch_queries) this page for more useful information.